Entity Framework SaveChanges; non-nullable DateTime with default value GetDate()
I have a table defined as:
CREATE TABLE ServiceLog
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    UpdateDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
    Entry varchar(max) NOT NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE ServiceLog 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ServiceLog_UpdateDateTime  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR UpdateDateTime

I've generated the EF model from the database and the class for the table looks like this:
public partial class ServiceLog
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
     public string Entry { get; set; }
}

When attempting to insert a row with the following code:
db.Set<ServiceLog>().Add(new ServiceLog { Entry = "log entry" });
db.SaveChanges();

I get an error

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

When I look at the SQL generated, it's trying to insert the data value '1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM', which SQL Server doesn't like.
All this makes perfect sense, but I'd prefer to let the database server insert the date/time, and I've got another application that has exactly the same table setup, imported EF setup and C# code, and that works fine and doesn't attempt to insert the UpdateDateTime.
So the question is: where could I start looking to find the difference between the two apps?
THANKS

Entry varchar(max) ? You expect to store a 2GB ASCII file in there?

Please read the error DateTime in both C# and SQL Server has no format, it's a binary value. The error doesn't complain about a non-existing format. It says you tried to store an out-of-range value. The legacy SQL Server type datetime can't handle 0001-01-01. The default didn't work because the value isn't missing.  System.DateTime is a struct which means it always has a value, just like int. If you don't set it, the default value is 0001-01-01

How about modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceLog>().Property(sl => sl.UpdateDateTime).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); or modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceLog>().Property(x => x.UpdateDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()"); while configuring your entities in dbcontext

What does the model configuration look like? Without at least .Property(x => x.UpdateDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql EF has no idea that this property has a default and will try to save the actual value specified by the application, ie 0001-01-01

Thanks Ali, Panagiotis! HasDefaultValueSql provided the solution. In regards varchar(max) - is there a downside to using that as opposed to varchar(n) where n will be a big number that should be long enough?

Ali and Panagiotis provided the answer with the HasDefaultValueSql property. Mine is a database first model, so I found the table in the diagram and set the StoreGeneratedPattern property of the UpdateDateTime column to Computed:

